# How to use a slice as a stack in a loop

Tags: go, slice

I am using a slice as a stack.

When I do this

```
stack := make([]int, 0)
stack = append(stack, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
for len(stack) != 0 {
    var a int
    a, stack = stack[len(stack) - 1], stack[:len(stack) - 1]
    fmt.Print(a)
}
```

I get the output

```
54321
```

as expected.

When I do this

```
stack := make([]int, 0)
stack = append(stack, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a, stack := stack[len(stack) - 1], stack[:len(stack) - 1]
fmt.Println(a, len(stack))
```

I get the output

```
5 4
```

as expected. However, when I try to combine these by doing this

```
stack := make([]int, 0)
stack = append(stack, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
for len(stack) != 0 {
    a, stack := stack[len(stack) - 1], stack[:len(stack) - 1]
    fmt.Print(a)
}
```

the result is a compile error

> unused variable 'stack'

This confuses me. I thought I could use `:=` as long as at least one of the variables is being declared (in this case `a`), and that `stack` would just get reassigned. However I am clearly wrong. Can anybody explain why the line

```
a, stack := stack[len(stack) - 1], stack[:len(stack) - 1]
```

doesn't work in the loop, and how I can do "pop" as a one-liner in a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:=` only assigns a new value to an existing variable if the variable was declared earlier *in the same block* and has the correct type. Otherwise, it creates a new variable. Since your loop is a new block, with a new scope, you get a new `stack`, which is then never used for anything. There's no way to "halfway" do a `:=`, so you simply can't have a one-liner here. You'll have to

```
var a int
a, stack = stack[len(stack)-1], stack[:len(stack)-1]
```

or else create a type and a method (with the stack as a pointer receiver) so that you can

```
a := stack.Pop()
```